# Android aws SDK show progress for upload, not returning the bytes transfered

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Am uploading an image to Amazon server using the AWS SDK, Here i want the progress of the upload to update my progress bar. But am not getting the number of bytes being transfered.

Here is my code:

```
final File image = new File(imagePath);

                s3Client.createBucket(Constants.getPictureBucket());
                // Content type is determined by file extension.
                PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(Constants.getPictureBucket(),
                        obj.stackItem.ItemId + ".jpg", image);

                s3Client.putObject(por);

                Log.d("UploadTaskScheduler", "Photo Name: " + obj.stackItem.ItemName);

                por.setProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
                    int total = 0;

                    @Override
                    public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent pv) {
                        total += (int) pv.getBytesTransfered();
                        Log.d("UploadTaskScheduler", "BytesTransfered: " + total);
                    }

                });
```

It prints the first log that is the name of the file. But the second log is not even printed.

Comment: I help maintain the AWS SDK for Android, could you let us know what version of the SDK you are using and what API level you are building against?

Comment: What is obj here. I am facing similar problem while upload image from android to aws with Image path instead of image picker from gallery.

Comment: Hi, Same as i do to upload image to Amazon server using the AWS SDK version aws-android-sdk-2.1.4. The aws-android-sdk-2.1.4-s3.debug.jar file only added in my libs folder. And I get error for "BasicAWSCredentials cannot be resolved to a type". I couldn't import "BasicAWSCredentials". Please help me?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reviewing your code, I've noticed that you are setting the progress listener after starting the upload.

You'll want to move the `por.setProgressListener(...);` before the `s3Client.putObject(por);` at which point you should see the progress for your upload.

Comment: awesome!! thanks for the help.. But one last question, How to get more logs in the sense now my files are pretty small 100kb, so the log prints 0, 80, 100. For some files 0, 100 directly..

Comment: @sukarno Unfortunately there is currently no control over the interval of the progress you will receive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {

            long _bytesCurrent = bytesCurrent;
            long _bytesTotal = bytesTotal;


            float percentage =  ((float)_bytesCurrent /(float)_bytesTotal * 100);
            Log.d("percentage","" +percentage);

            progressbar.setProgress(percentage);
        }
```